# Example of a CW complex that is not a $\Delta$-complex?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Hatcher notes in chapter 2.1 (in the paragraph just preceding the section on simplicial homology (page 104 in my edition)), that all $\Delta$-complexes can be realized as CW complexes with some added restrictions on the characteristic maps. Is there a simple example of a CW complex that is not a $\Delta$-complex?

Comment: Take the unique cell complex which has one $0$-cell and one $2$-cell.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. Can you explain a bit more? It seems like you've just described $S^2$. Is the idea basically that the restriction to each of its boundaries of the characteristic map of the 2-cell can't be a characteristic map for a 1-cell because there are no 1-cells? So would any space that admits a CW complex structure with an $n$-cell but no $(n-1)$-cell be an example?

Comment: Yes, this is a cell decomposition of $S^2$, and yes any such similar example would work.

Comment: Great, thanks so much! If you want to write exactly your first comment as a solution I will accept it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure every $\Delta$ complex is at least homotopy equivalent to a CW complex

Comment: Or the other way around

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the unique cell complex which has one $0$-cell and one $2$-cell.

Comment: Is this because $\partial \Delta^2 \to S^2$ is not injective on the interior of $\Delta^1$?

Comment: @wolfgang Even easier, there are no $1$-cells.

Comment: I see. Does that mean in a $\Delta$-complex, we cannot skip dimensions?

Comment: @Wolfgang, it is true that you can't skip dimensions.

Comment: But it is possible to show that there is a $\Delta$-complex structure on $S^2$, you just start with one 0-cell, attach one 1-cell in the only way possible (getting $S^1$), and then attach two 2-cells in a smart way to get $S^2$ (each 2-cell will be a hemisphere). This is a $\Delta$-complex structure. Is there any example of a topological space that admits a CW structure but no $\Delta$-complex structure?

Comment: @TheGiraffeGuy, that's a different question, but the answer is yes. If you make the attaching map for a cell too wiggly there is no delta complex structure. I seem to recall there is an example in Hatcher. One way is to attach a $2$ cell along its boundary to the rest of the complex with a local model of $y=\sin (1/x)$, folding it  over and over at smaller scales.